# Ionic upload multiple files to php api

Tags: php, api, ionic-framework, ionic3, silex

I have an Ionic app that lets users upload 5 videos to the server in order to get one video compilation of their videos. So far I can upload only one video and grab it in my PHP Silex API.

This is my Ionic code

```
_upload(index){
console.log(index);

if(index >= this.favorites.length) return;

this.http
.uploadFile(this.apiLink + 'user/upload', {}, {}, this.favorites[index], 'file')
.then(data => {

    if(index == this.favorites.length) this.loaderBox.dismiss();
    console.log("Done for index : "+index+"| data :"+JSON.stringify(data));
    this._upload(index + 1);
})
.catch(err => { 
    console.error("Error index "+index+" | error "+JSON.stringify(err));
 }) 
}
```

PHP code:

```
$app->post('/user/upload', function(Request $request) use($app) {
session_start();
$file = $request->files->get('file');    
if( !isset($_SESSION['files']) )
{
    $_SESSION['files'] = [];
} 
$files = $_SESSION['files']; 
array_push($files,$file);
$_SESSION['files'] = $files; 
if(count($_SESSION['files']) == 5){
    $rsp = upload($_SESSION['files']); 
    $_SESSION['files'] = []; 
    return $app->json(array('response'=>$rsp));
}
});
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your specific problem is? Are you trying to let users upload multiple videos?

Comment: @divibisan yes a user can upload his 5 videos taken by the camera inside the app and then upload them to the api, the api runs an ffmpeg command a return the link to the compiled video

Comment: Can you clarify your question, then? The more specific your question is, the sooner you'll get good answers. The code you posted lets the user upload a single file. Are you trying to save the uploaded files so the user can process them once 5 are uploaded? Or are you trying to implement a single function to upload 5 files at once?

Comment: @divibisan The _upload function is a recursive one since i can only upload a single file at once i tried to make that recursive function and start with index 0 so it will upload all 5 videos in an array. In the Php code since i only get one file per request i'm trying to store each video in the session until the api gets all 5 videos then process them. Anything will work for me at this point, i only want to upload 5 videos and catch them in the api so i can process them and send back the final video.